# Docusign Basic API Limitations

Tags: api, docusignapi

<--------- UNNECESSARY BACKGROUND INFO --------->
I have a client who wanted a simple contract run through docusign. I created a form, he fills the form with basic information, and then docusign sends a contract to his customer with the information populated.  So I sign up with a demo API account and get everything going.  After about a week, I have everything perfect and am ready to roll with a live account.  I sign up for the Basic API for $50/month and upload the template from the demo account.  It doesn't let me do it, because my account is not allowed to use calculated fields.  Fine, I remove the 3 calculated fields and try again.  Now it says I can't use conditional fields (which isn't mentioned in the API pricing on the website).  Then I look to see that the Basic API doesn't even have data labels!  I can't pay for the Advanced API for this one form that will get used maybe 10 times per month.
<--------- QUESTION STARTS HERE --------->
Can I pre-populate documents with the Docusign API using "settexttabs" if I have a Basic API account?  If so, how can it be done without data labels available?
Is there an alternative option that doesn't require a higher level API purchase?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which plan and which feature you are referring to (https://www.docusign.com/products-and-pricing) but I every plan allows for API use. I suspect you need advanced fields and that is only available in the $40 plan (not $50) but I'm not clear on which feature exactly you are trying to use.